# Apply a function to all dict elements of an array in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, generator

Hi I am wondering what would be the best way to apply a function to all elements of an array (those elements are dict). I have dict object that contains elements, one of them being another array of dict.
I want to avoid doing the following

```
my_array = api.get_elements().json() # return an array of dict
for elem in my_array:
    for sub_elem in elem['sub_array']: # here I access the the sub array
        process(sub_elem)
```

process would be a function where I modify some values of my sub_elem.
From what I read so far I could use the map() function like

```
map_res = map(process, elem['sub_array'])
```

or I could use a list comprehension

```
res = [process(sub_elem) for sub_elem in elem['sub_array']]
```

and then someone told me I could also use generator because he told me it's better for memory when dealing with large data. The problem is that he didn't tell me how. So I tried it my way:

```
processed_data_generator = (process(d) for d in elem['sub_array'])

def process(elem: dict):
    elem['name'] = 'NAME'

for processed_dict in processed_data_generator:
    print(processed_dict)
```

but I am not sure do I have to return the item? Put yield statement? because I can't find a way to access the result of generator right now and it seems like my code is not doing anything besides "initializing" a generator object.

What would be the correct way to deal with my problem?

Comment: What do you want to return from process function? `elem['name'] = 'NAME'` is assignment operation.

Comment: I am working with dictionaries so I just want to do assignment I don't think I need to return anything actually. But if I don't return anything I feel like the generator is not doing anything

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be solved by recursive function call like below implementation.
Code is based on Python 3.

```
import collections.abc

def map_nested_dicts_modify(ob, func):
    for k, v in ob.items():
        if isinstance(v, collections.abc.Mapping):
            map_nested_dicts_modify(v, func)
        else:
            func(v)

map_nested_dicts_modify(my_array, process)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply it does work this way yes. However, I was trying to make use of the following methods listed in my first message. But I still appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1):

You got it right:

First check what your function is returning. You need a `return` keyword to return something from your function. Like

```
def process(elem: dict):
    return elem['name'] = 'NAME'  # you are assigning 'NAME' value to 'name' key in elem dictionary.
```

Once you understand your function correctly, you can jump to generator.

```
processed_data_generator = (process(d) for d in elem['sub_array'])  # you are applying function process on each item(d) in elem['sub_array']
```

---

If you want to view the complete generator in one go you can do:

```
list(processed_data_generator)
```

Want to see individual elements then:

```
for processed_dict in processed_data_generator:
    print(processed_dict)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, it works but I thought when working with generator I had to use the yield keyword? If I use it here it seems to not work and if I use return it works fine.

Comment: @ElPandario yield keyword is not mandatory; you can get generator from tuple comprehension. They are just like list comprehension but they have round brackets `()`